# Как правильно синтаксически оформить код (HTML5)?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, веб-программирование

Как правильно синтаксически оформить код? Есть такой вот блок с текстом как на изображении : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сверстал его так - HTML :

```
<div class="block_2">

<div class="container_block">

<div class="button_mnu">
<!--Интерактивная кнопка, раскрывающая меню -->
    <img src="img/buttn_mnu.png" width="33px" height="29px" alt="">
</div>

<div class="title_project">

    <div class="title_1">
    <p>Ali Sayed's</p>
    </div>

    <div class="title_2">
    <p>Web Designing</p>
    </div>

    <div class="title_3">
    <p>Project</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="text_info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.</p>

    <p>quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper
    suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea ommodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dol.</p>
</div>
```

Но код выглядит слишком громоздким, много классов, также много css - кода получатся, понимаю, что можно сделать проще, но пока не могу додуматься как. Прошу помочь советом.

p.s. Кнопку меню оформил временно картинкой.

Comment: если html5 то ни каких div class="" не должно быть , только теги html5

Comment: @Geyan ну это уже слишком жестоко

Comment: @andreymal почему же ? вопрос о html5 а пространство имён в html5 очень сжато - aside section article итд , вы же не хуже меня это знаете

Comment: @Geyan тегов там всё равно не на все случаи жизни, и использовать css-классы никто не запрещал

Comment: @andreymal  тогда это уже не html5 , а вот объявлять тегам html5 id или class ни какая спецификация не запрещает

Comment: Разве конкретно этот блок одними тегами html5 опишешь? Разве они здесь по смыслу уместны? У меня на каждый абзац из этого блока свой класс, т.к. абзацы оформлены тремя разными шрифтами и я не знал как их оформить, если не применить к каждому класс.  Разве нельзя сделать как-то проще?

Comment: Лично мне кажется, что тут всё норм, только в `width="33px" height="29px"` убрать px, ибо там и так только пиксели указываются

Comment: я не сенсей и не гуру , но вот это что на скрине - вмещается в html5 в полне , доказывать не хочу

Comment: да и выглядит прилично , мир клином же не сошёлся на html5 , можете даже свои теги придумать - только проблемы с валидатором будут

Comment: @Geyan, какие странные комментарии у вопроса. Спецификация HTML5 включает большинство тегов HTML4 и не ограничивает пространство только вновь введенными тегами. Или я пропустил какой-то новый тренд в верстке?

Comment: @AlexKrass я спорить не буду , но html5 это прежде всего семантика http://webformyself.com/html5-elementy-novye-tegi/

Comment: В чем проблема у автора, я понять не могу? в смысле элегантно?

Comment: автор, а вы о БЭМ слышали? Вы ужаснетесь, увидев такое количество классов.

Comment: width="33px" height="29px" это единственное не адекватное в твоем коде, фу так делать. Код должен быть читабельным как и верстка, пофиг на количество классов, почитай БЭМ, это полезно для общего развития

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```css
.container_block h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px 0
}
.container_block h2 span {
  display: block;
}
.container_block h2 span:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #666;
}
.container_block h2 span:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.container_block h2 span:nth-child(3) {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.container_block > p {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_block">

  <div class="button_mnu">
    <!--Интерактивная кнопка, раскрывающая меню -->
    <img src="img/buttn_mnu.png" width="33" height="29" alt="">
  </div>

  <h2>
    <span>Ali Sayed's</span>
    <span>Web Designing</span>
    <span>Project</span>
  </h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.</p>
  <p>quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea ommodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dol.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: использование `:nth-child` плохая практика..

Comment: @Nikolay как по мне,  так намного приятнее, чем бэм на каждое слово вешать